# how to add progress view in moya swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, moya

how to add progress view in moya swift ?,
is this correct. is this a correct way to use progressblock.

```
let instance = MoyaProvider<ServiceType>()

    self.view.showLoadingHUD()

    instance.request(.GetRouteDetail, callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main, progress: { (response) in

        if response.completed{

            self.view.hideLoadingHUD()
        }else{

            self.view.showLoadingHUD()
        }

    }) { (result) in

        switch result{
        case .success(let response):
            print(response)

        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)
            self.view.hideLoadingHUD()
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Anbu.karthik  why u deleted ur answer?

Comment: I reopned my answer check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just modify the `hideLoadingHud` in inside the success or failure block. bz that part result handler

```
 let instance = MoyaProvider<ServiceType>()

    self.view.showLoadingHUD()

    instance.request(.GetRouteDetail, callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main, progress: { (response) in



    }) { (result) in
         self.view.hideLoadingHUD()
        switch result{
        case .success(let response):
            print(response)

        case .failure(let error):

            print(error)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simple hide your `LoadingHUD` in the result closure only

```
let instance = MoyaProvider<ServiceType>()

self.view.showLoadingHUD()

instance.request(.GetRouteDetail, callbackQueue: DispatchQueue.main, progress: { (response) in
// You can update the progress percent ...here or ignore it
}) { (result) in
    self.view.hideLoadingHUD()

    switch result{
    case .success(let response):
        print(response)
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: what happen if api failed?

Comment: @VasanthanPrem - if api failed it automatically reach the failure part